# Filter on annotation - SPARQL

Tags: regex, filter, annotations, sparql

I want to query my [ontology](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=17434206222510754967) based on annotations with datatype of float and string.
For instance I have an individual that has an annotation "EBC_value" of type float and an annotation "Label" of type String.

How do I do this? I have tried with REGEX, like this, but it doesn´t work. I don´t get any errors, just no results.

```
PREFIX ont: <http://vestbrygg.no/ontologies/beer.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT  ?title
WHERE   { ?x ont:title ?title
          FILTER regex(?title, "Sack") 
        }
```

Hope you guys can help. Thanks.And yeah, unless you want to see and test the entire ontology,
the code for the annotations are like this:

```
<NamedIndividual rdf:about="&beer;Base_malt_-_Best_Malz">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&beer;Light"/>
    <beer:EBC_value rdf:datatype="&xsd;float"></beer:EBC_value>
    <beer:Label rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Sack</beer:Label>
</NamedIndividual>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query bears no relation to your data which is why you get no results.

Firstly the `ont:title` property that your query references does not appear to exist in your data.

Secondly your namespaces don't appear to align, I assume the `ont` namespace in your query is supposed to be the same namespace as the `beer` namespace in your RDF/XML but you haven't shown the namespaces so I can only guess at this.  Even though namespaces are mostly a convenience mechanism it's best to be consistent with your use of prefixes because it'll make things a lot less confusing.

Thirdly there should be absolutely no need to use `REGEX()` you simply need to use an appropriate graph pattern:

```
PREFIX beer: <http://vestbrygg.no/ontologies/beer.owl#>

SELECT ?x
WHERE
{
  ?x beer:Label "Sack" .
}
```

Since `beer:Label` is a property you can access it directly in your query.  This will find you all individuals where the `beer:Label` property has the value `Sack`, if you want to do a partial match on the search string you can always use the [`CONTAINS()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains) function which will be faster than `REGEX()`:

```
PREFIX beer: <http://vestbrygg.no/ontologies/beer.owl#>

SELECT ?x
WHERE
{
  ?x beer:Label ?label .
  FILTER(CONTAINS(?label, "Sack"))
}
```

This will find all individuals where there is a `beer:Label` and it contains the value `Sack`

#### Edit

To answer your comment, matching typed values requires you to know what the type of the values are, assuming you are using `xsd:float` then you'd query like the following:

```
PREFIX beer: <http://vestbrygg.no/ontologies/beer.owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?x
WHERE
{
  ?x beer:EBC_value "4.8"^^xsd:float .
}
```

Comment: Thanks ALOT. What about float-values?
I also have a property beer:EBC_value which I need to query.

Comment: If you are new to SPARQL can I suggest reading either the popular [SPARQL by Example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example) tutorial or getting your hands on a copy of the excellent [Learning SPARQL](http://www.learningsparql.com) text book