# how to get individuals, object properties and data properties belonging to a class and also has a specific annotation in sparql

Tags: rdf, sparql, ontology

I want to retrieve the individuals, object properties and data properties from my ontology that belongs to a class and also that has a given annotation.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wel: <http://www.semanticweb.org/dell/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-11#>

SELECT *
WHERE {?s a wel:Sentence1 }
```

Using the above code I can get all the individuals, object properties and data properties that belongs to class `wel:Sentence1`. But my target is to get the individuals, object properties and data properties that belongs to class `wel:Sentence1` and that has the annotation

```
wel:belongs_to_story="SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"
```

I followed the method given in [Filter on annotation - SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20101247/1281433), but I don't get any answers. This is my query.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wel: <http://www.semanticweb.org/dell/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-11#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?s wel:belongs_to_story ?label  .
  FILTER(CONTAINS(?label, "SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"))
}
```

One portion of the data that includes the `belongs_to_story` property is the description of the SnowWhite individual:

```xml
<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/dell/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-11#SnowWhite -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-11;SnowWhite">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;Heroien"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:appearance>beatiful</untitled-ontology-11:appearance>
    <untitled-ontology-11:quality>kind</untitled-ontology-11:quality>
    <untitled-ontology-11:appearance>loving</untitled-ontology-11:appearance>
    <untitled-ontology-11:appearance>fairest</untitled-ontology-11:appearance>
    <untitled-ontology-11:ate rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;Apple"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:loves rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;Prince"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:belongs_to_story rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:heroienOf rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:livedWith rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;StepMother"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:sleptOn rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;bed"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:saw rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;beds"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:livedIn rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;castle"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:saw rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;chairs"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:saw rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;cottage"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:wentIn rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;cottage"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:saw rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;cups"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:fellOn rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;dead"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:fellOn rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;ground"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:combed rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;hair"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:ranInto rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;jungle"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:felt rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;tired"/>
</NamedIndividual>
```

Another is an axiom that has an annotation:

```xml
<Axiom>
    <untitled-ontology-11:seq rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;Sentence2"/>
    <annotatedSource rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;SnowWhite"/>
    <untitled-ontology-11:belongs_to_story rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"/>
    <annotatedTarget rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;StepMother"/>
    <annotatedProperty rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;livedWith"/>
</Axiom>
```

I want to connect those two queries. Please help.

Comment: We need to see your data.  Without seeing your data, we can only guess why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology indicates that there might be some conceptual misunderstanding

> ```sql
> SELECT *
> WHERE {?s a wel:Sentence1 }
> ```
>
> Using the above code I can get all the individuals, object properties
>   and data properties that belongs to class `wel:Sentence1`.

If you're working in OWL, and `wel:Sentence` is an OWL class, then the only things that should be in triples of the form `?s a wel:Sentence1` are individuals.  Only individuals belong to OWL classes;  object properties and data properties don't belong to OWL classes, so there shouldn't be any object properties or data properties belonging to `wel:Sentence1` to retrieve at all.

At any rate, `a` is just shorthand for the property `rdf:type`. It sounds like you're trying to retrieve individuals that have the string `"SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"` as the value of the property `wel:belongs_to_story`, in which case you should be able to use the query

```sql
#-- ...prefixes...

select * where {
  ?s wel:belongs_to_story "SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"
}
```

However, [your data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/15uih5cirlzimm3/welota.owl?token_hash=AAENG7n9uiVUrnhEskiWnqgwWP9mbVqw8tLUyaRdO41Cpw) actually looks more like this (from the link that you provided):

```xml
<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/dell/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-11#SnowWhite -->

<NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-11;SnowWhite">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;Heroien"/>
    <!-- … -->
    <untitled-ontology-11:belongs_to_story rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-11;SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs"/>
    <!-- … -->
</NamedIndividual>
```

The value of the `belongs_to_story` property isn't a string;  it's another resource, identified by an IRI that would be abbreviated as `SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs`.  This is actually a bit clearer if you use the more human readable Turtle serialization, where your data would then be:

```
wel:SnowWhite  a              wel:Heroien , owl:NamedIndividual ;
        # …
        wel:belongs_to_story  wel:SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs ;
        # …
        wel:saw               wel:beds , wel:cups , wel:cottage , wel:chairs ;
        wel:sleptOn           wel:bed ;
        wel:wentIn            wel:cottage .
```

The Turtle serialization is actually very similar to the SPARQL syntax.  Your query needs to be the following (with results generated by Jena's command line tools):

```sql
prefix wel: <http://www.semanticweb.org/dell/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-11#>

select * where {
  ?s wel:belongs_to_story wel:SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs
}
```

```
------------------
| s              |
==================
| _:b0           |
| wel:castle     |
| _:b1           |
| wel:SnowWhite  |
| wel:StepMother |
------------------
```

The blank nodes (indicated by `_:b0` and `_:b1` are the axioms that you've annotated:

```
[ a                         owl:Axiom ;
  wel:belongs_to_story
          wel:SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs ;
  wel:seq  wel:Sentence1 ;
  owl:annotatedProperty     wel:livedIn ;
  owl:annotatedSource       wel:SnowWhite ;
  owl:annotatedTarget       wel:castle
] .

[ a                         owl:Axiom ;
  wel:belongs_to_story
          wel:SnowWhiteAndTheSevenDwarfs ;
  wel:seq  wel:Sentence2 ;
  owl:annotatedProperty     wel:livedWith ;
  owl:annotatedSource       wel:SnowWhite ;
  owl:annotatedTarget       wel:StepMother
] .
```

Comment: My file is saved in rdf format. Is there a way I can upload my file?

Comment: this is my data, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/15uih5cirlzimm3/welota.owl?token_hash=AAENG7n9uiVUrnhEskiWnqgwWP9mbVqw8tLUyaRdO41Cpw

Comment: Thank you, but not everyone reads the comments, and dropbox files don't remain for every.  Please take at least some of the content there, use the "Edit" link under your question, and update the question with this information.

Comment: @user3462940 Even so, I've updated the answer based on your data.  Looks like it should work, now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This method really fits my purpose. :)